# to set the spinner using java coding

Tags: java, android, spinner

please tell me how to set the spinner according to the integer value in java coding.

my spinner is,

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/gender_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
    android:entries="@array/gender_list"
     />
```

and in strings i have added,

```
 <string-array name="gender_list">
    <item>Male</item>
    <item>Female</item>
    <item>Others</item>
</string-array>
```

i have an integer value as,

```
gender = Integer.parseInt(strLine[9]);
```

Is this the correct way to set the spinner..??

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.gender_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            egender.setAdapter(adapter);
                            egender.setSelection(gender);
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the value from the server and store it in integer Variable 'pos'

```
  egender.setSelection(pos);
```

and then set the selection.

Comment: am getting either of these 3 values 0,1 or 2 from the server and am storing it in gender and set ht e spinner as, gender = Integer.parseInt(strLine[9]); so u mean what anm doing is correct???